# Magento: limit product max quantity to 1 per order. quantity 2 = 2 orders

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.6

Is it anyhow possible to limit specific products in Magento to a max quantity of one per order? This means the user can only order one product at a time. If he wants to order the product twice he has to do a second order. This is very important for me for the later order workflow.

Thx for your help, I appreciate it!

Kind regards, Manu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can limit the maximum quantity of a product in the shopping cart by editing the value on the **Inventory** tab when editing a product. See screenshot below. In your case, you'd want to uncheck `Use Config Settings` and set the value to `1`.

[image: Product page Inventory tab]

Comment: ok, maybe I was not specific enough. I meant a total of 1 product can be ordert. Your configuration only limits a specific product to be ordered once.

Comment: This param means that you can buy 10000 at a time. One client can buy 10000 items per one order. If he wants then 1000 items again per next order. And so again and again.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but if I have 2 products (A and B) with max qty 1 I still can order 2 Products: 1x product A and 1x product B. However a customer should only be able to oder ONE product at all. So a customer can either order product A or product B. You know a solution for this too?

Comment: I would suggest modifying `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct()` to disallow adding items if the cart already has quantity (see `getItemsQty()`). You should also be aware of `updateItem()` which could be used to change the quantity of items in one's cart.

Answer (score 2):

Well above answer is useful to restrict a single product to add in cart not for Restricting Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Car. To change this setting fallow bellow steps.

First login into Magento admin then 
Go to **System>>Configuration** then use this configuration settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento Maximum Allowed Order Amount](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/), you would have to create a custom module to add this feature.

Create an observer for `sales_quote_save_before`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <inchoo_maxorderamount_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
                        <class>inchoo_maxorderamount/observer</class>
                        <method>enforceSingleOrderLimit</method>
                    </inchoo_maxorderamount_enforceSingleOrderLimit>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In your observer

```
class Inchoo_MaxOrderAmount_Model_Observer
{
    private $_helper;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_helper = Mage::helper('inchoo_maxorderamount');
    }
    /**
     * No single order can be placed over the amount of X
     */
    public function enforceSingleOrderLimit($observer)
    {
        if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if ($quote->getCart()->getItemsCount() == 1) {

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('limit only one product per order');
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason its not displaying errors. I've set ini and error reporting options in index.php so I'm trying to figure out why its just a white screen now.

Answer (score 0):

The below should fix your issue:

```
public function enforceSingleOrderLimit($observer){
     if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
        return;
    }
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    if ($cart->getItemsCount() > 1) {

        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('limit only one product per order');
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```