# Magento cart can only take one item

Tags: cart, magento-1.6

Our cart is facing the following issue - you can add one item to the cart - but not a second one. I have already check all the obvious in the system section for restrictions on the quantity (e.g. [Unable to add product quantity more than one items in one order MAGENTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239431/unable-to-add-product-quantity-more-than-one-items-in-one-order-magento)) - cookie life time - and many more. No misconfiguration was found. I am using Magento 1.6.2.0. The error was reproduced in Chrome and Safari on Mac OS X many times in a row. I am sorry that I can not post an URL. Moreover there is to know that the run-time environment is an Amazon EC2/RDS Service.

Comment: The question you posted a link to shows that you can set up quantity restriction, have you ? did you install any plugin that messed it up or right after you installed Magento this behavior started ?

Comment: In the meantime I found out that the session is dropping - any suggestions on where the configuration (server or Magento) can cause such problems? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the session is not stored. Can you make sure the cookie is set on the correct domain and the sessions are stored properly?

In case you're using file based sessions it could be the files can't be created due to permission issues in the `var/session` directory