# How to limit maximum items of order by country in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can I limit maximum items of order by **country** or by **continent**?

I know we can set the limit in the config just as this answer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856770/magento-limit-product-max-quantity-to-1-per-order-quantity-2-2-orders).

But what about I just want to limit it by country or by continent?

For instance, I just want to allow **max** items of **120** per product that are shipped to France and then **60** items only for the shipping outside France.

My store is set in France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tealuo,  i have find a temporary solution for this  works

Here step on details:

1.copy `app>code>core>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Observer.php`  to `app>code>local>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Observer.php`

And goto function checkQuoteItemQty() add below

`$county=null;
$country=$quoteItem->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id');`
after

```
if (!$quoteItem || !$quoteItem->getProductId() || !$quoteItem->getQuote()
            || $quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
            return $this;
        }
```

Then in this function  change

```
$result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($rowQty, $qtyForCheck, $qty);
```

to

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($rowQty, $qtyForCheck, $qty,$country);
```

And
from

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($optionQty, $qtyForCheck, $optionValue);
```

to

```
 $result = $stockItem->checkQuoteItemQty($optionQty, $qtyForCheck, $optionValue,$country);
```

2. copy app>code>core>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Stock>Item.php
   to  app>code>local>Mage>CatalogInventory>Model>Stock>Item.php

edit `checkQuoteItemQty` function:

edit below code

```
      if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > $this->getMaxSaleQty()) {
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$county_id)
        )
        ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
        ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
     }
```

To:

```
if(!is_null($county_id) && $county_id=='IN'){
    if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > 2) {
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$county_id)
        )
        ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
        ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
     }


}
else{
      if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > $this->getMaxSaleQty()) {
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is %s. %s', $this->getMaxSaleQty() * 1,$county_id)
        )
        ->setErrorCode('qty_max')
        ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
     }

}
```

See code

```
if(!is_null($county_id) && $county_id=='IN'){
means IN=India country code of India,Just change country IN to FR France country code
```

And see condition `if ($this->getMaxSaleQty() && $qty > 2)  change  2 to 60`
And According to  your reference 
[Magento: limit product max quantity to 1 per order. quantity 2 = 2 orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856770/magento-limit-product-max-quantity-to-1-per-order-quantity-2-2-orders)

make `Maximum  Allow Qty in Shopping cart to 120`

Importnote: this->getProductId() is given product id.

Comment: thanks Amit. But where in the code can I set 120 for France and 60 for any country outside France? Thanks.